# Не запускается Activity из Сервиса

Tags: android-studio, activity, service

Итак, так как прошлый вопрос закрыли, объясню по простому. Есть обычный, самый обычный сервис. Не IntentService, не JobIntentService. В нем самый обычный код, ничего мудрого.

```
val Main = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
val handler = Handler()
thread{
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    handler.post{
        startActivity(Main)
    }
}
```

В чем же проблема? При запуске этого кода, через 5 секунд Main не запускается, а телефон пишет, что "Все приложения, связанные с этим действием, были отключены, заблокированы, или же не были установлены". Телефон старый, Samsung Galaxy J5 (2016 года), OC Android 7.1.1, может в нем проблема. Также, ещё одна деталь, до этого я пытался запустить Main при помощи while(true) без thread. Но тогда Main включался 1 раз и опять выскакивали те же ошибки.
Я не знаю, что ещё вам нужно для деталей, если нужен код какого-то файла, скину обязательно.

Ошибка в logcat

> D/Instrumentation: checkStartActivityResult() : mdm admin has blocked start activity Intent { cmp=/com.example.myapplication.TimerWarning2 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }

Манифест

``

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".TimerWarning2"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name=".CountDownService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Helper"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

``

Comment: Добро пожаловать к нам на сайт! У нас тут есть определённые правила, следуя которым высока вероятность получить какую-то помощь. Отредактируйте,пж-та,вопрос, убрав мат и добавив логи ошибки. По идее в LogCat должно быть что-то полезное. Просто описание текста ошибки, который показывается юзеру обычно слабо помогает в решении программной проблемы. Ну и я лично вообще не уверен, что вашу задумку можно реализовать. На новых версиях ОС, вроде, запрещено активити из фона открывать. Так что вам надо ещё указать версию ОС телефона и на каких версиях оно должно работать. Возможно вам надо иначе делать

Comment: Хорошо, 5 минут и будет исправлено

Comment: Попробуйте логи в вопрос добавить и покажите манифест

Comment: Все добавил, если еще что-то нужно, могу скинуть

Comment: Судя по гуглу, у вас на девайсе какое-то админское приложение установлено, видимо оно имеет белый список приложений, которые разрешено запускать. Попробуйте не использовать этот девайс для тестов и/или отключите это админское приложение или разрешите в нём запуск вашего. Если же критично важно на подобных девайсах запускать - надо решать как-то вопрос с запросом у юзера разрешения - типа в настройки какие-то его направлять.